# When I boot in centOS 8 I get some sign on my screen

Tags: centos, administration

After I boot in my centOS 8 I get [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De7GF.png) on display. And nothing is changed when I reboot my system.
When I click on this "icon" - left click give nothing, right clik give me option to change background image, like I click anywhere on screen. Also, when right shift is pressed this icon disappear.

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of the entire screen?

Comment: I can, but it's useless because on entire screen is my background image. Nothing else.Just this "icon", my background image, and top bar with clock and buttons for restart and poweroff. When I click on this "icon" - left click give nothing, right clik give me option to change background image, like I click anywhere on screen. Also, when right shift is pressed this icon disappear.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of gnome-settings-daemon which manages multimedia keys.